# File access from CentOS new HDD by web user

Tags: centos, hard-drive, symlink

I am using Centos 6.3 final and Apache 2.2.15. I recently installed a new HDD and created a symlink within my website's root directory so that my script can write big files to it and uses can access them through web. However, it looks like I misconfigured something or missed something and it's not working now.

This is what I did so far:

Old HDD: 
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/bigfile2 (symlink to link to folder below in new HDD)

New HDD: 
/newdisk/bigfile2

Now, my website php script writes files to new HDD properly but users can't access them from website. It gives 403, forbidden error when I try to visit mysite.com/bigfile2/file1.mov. I read a similar post here somewhere where someone mentioned about adding something like this within httpd.conf file maybe?

```
<Directory "/newdisk/bigfile2"> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride None 
Order Allow,Deny 
Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

And restart apache but still no luck! Do I need to add this to .htaccess ?

Any idea what am i missing? Note that i cannot use LVM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `semanage` to change the SELinux file context given to files created in the new location. `chcon` will allow you to change them so that your site will work. See the `httpd_selinux(8)`, `semanage(8)`, and `chcon(1)` man pages for details.